How can I smooth out White Jagged Edges in Greenscreen Keying in Compositor?
I have a greenscreen video footage of a person, and I’m using the Keying node in the Compositor to remove the green background. However, I’m encountering an issue with white, jagged edges around the person. I’m looking for a way to smooth out these edges while maintaining a crisp outline and avoiding a hard cut-out effect, especially around the hair. This is the original video:

Here’s what I’ve tried so far, but I’m facing some challenges. The jagged white edges are leading to a rough output and forcing me to apply excessive feathering.

What techniques or additional nodes can I use in the Compositor to achieve a smoother edge with a more natural, feathery effect? Any suggestions to refine the outline and eliminate the jagged edges would be greatly appreciated.

I think your main problem is that you aren't actually greenscreening the video here, you're using input video that has already had some kind of matting applied. That green background is artificial and the white artefacts around his ear and neck are visible there. It's going to be a challenge for sure when much of the "bad matte job look" you're trying to avoid has already been baked in. Do you not have the actual raw footage with no matting applied?

@Jakemoyo Yes, I used vmake to remove the background, but it didn’t do a good job, leaving white jagged areas. Since MP4 doesn’t support transparency, it just added a green background.

Yeah, I really think thats where most of the artefacts are coming from. I don't think you can squeeze blood from a stone here if you don't have a good base of footage to work from.

@Jakemoyo thank you for the confirmation! well I guess I'll just have to stick with that from Vmake. It's unfortunate that there aren't any free video background removers online that can produce HD footage for free. Adobe and CapCut used to have one but now it's for premium use only :(

You do have the raw footage though? You could still try to see if you could key that manually in Blender, maybe add a little manual roto. I don't think the only solution has to be using an AI to remove the BG and you're left to tidy up whatever it spits out.

@Jakemoyo yeah I have the actual footage https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vjLxY5OzrzMX9UFu2GG_D42oQnu7b05l?usp=sharing but it is white background and when I try to key it, it will also remove the parts of the face XD

Yeah, then maybe you can key it most of the way with the Keying node, get a clean background removal (with some of the face removed), then create a basic garbage matte via manual roto that covers most of the subject roughly (any old shape that covers the artefacts will do, it doesn't have to be pixel perfect), then just subtract that from the matte coming from the keying node. Don't feel like you gotta get it all done with one single step. Use two or three "rough" passes layered on top of eachother to get a clean final result.

@Jakemoyo I solved it via bash scripting to remove the background from the original video.

I was able to come up with a better solution that removes the background of the frames in the original video via bash scripting using rembg. The result is a PNG sequence.

rembg is an open-source Python package that utilizes AI models to
remove backgrounds from images. It’s designed to help users quickly
and efficiently eliminate backgrounds from various types of images.

Install it on your command line (Ubuntu App if you're using Windows) using pip
pip install rembg

And install all its dependencies:
pip install click
pip install filetype
pip install asyncer
pip install gradio
pip install aiohttp
pip install watchdog

Create a shell script extract_frames.sh with the following script which extracts all frames from your video:
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 --input <input_video> --output <output_folder>"
    exit 1
}

if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
    usage
fi

while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        --input) input_video="$2"; shift ;;
        --output) output_folder="$2"; shift ;;
        *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; usage ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [[ ! -f "$input_video" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Input video file does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "$output_folder"

ffmpeg -i "$input_video" -vf "fps=30" "$output_folder/%04d.png"

echo "Frames extracted to $output_folder"

And another shell script file remove_bg_frames.sh which will bulk remove the background for each image:
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 --input <input_folder> --output <output_folder>"
    exit 1
}

if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then
    usage
fi

while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        --input) input_folder="$2"; shift ;;
        --output) output_folder="$2"; shift ;;
        *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1"; usage ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [[ ! -d "$input_folder" ]]; then
    echo "Error: Input folder does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "$output_folder"

for img in "$input_folder"/*.png; do
    if [[ ! -f "$img" ]]; then
        echo "No PNG files found in the input folder."
        exit 1
    fi
    filename=$(basename "$img")
    rembg i "$img" "$output_folder/$filename"
    echo "Processed: $filename"
done

echo "Background removal completed. Check the output in $output_folder."

